# Can ASP.net MVC 2 Project and CMS can be Combined together

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed project using Asp.net MVC 2.Now the content part of My site i don't want to build a Cms for that So my question is can i used any existing CMS developed in **MVC2** so that The content part will be taken care of by the CMS 
and Application part by developed project by me.

I have used CMS like Silverstripe which is quite easy which also provides ORM to develop application on their Sapphire engine which but developed in PHP.

If it is Combined then when writing Code i will write like this

[This just Sample Imaginary Code.I just want CMS to be easy]

```
 <logo><Pick_up_from_CMS ID=logo></logo>
    <menu><Pick_up_from_CMS ID=menu></menu>

        <header><Pick_up_from_CMS ID=header></header>

        <body>
        <Pick_up_from_CMS ID=body>

        <MY_Application_Logic ID=Logic1><!--This May be my Registration or Search form> -->
        </body>
        <footer><Pick_up_from_CMS ID=footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, yes.

It won't be easy though. A lot of the Content Management Systems out there rely on their own set of ASP.NET WebForms user controls to provide content functionality.

If you're going to integrate a ASP.NET WebForms CMS with ASP.NET MVC 2, you're going to have to do your integration at the API level (assuming the CMS has an API).

That will allow you to retreive and insert your content in your controller without having to use any WebForms User Controls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.any of the cms you Know which provide it?